# Create crystal reports formula with various fields which can contain NULL value

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula

I want to create a address field that contains various database fields. However when one of these value is NULL then the fields after that NULL value are not shown anymore.

For example in my formula the field BlockS is NULL. Because of that the value in CountryS field is not shown anymore. How can I make sure that dispite there are NULL values all the fields that do have values are shown?

```
  IF ISNULL({Header.StreetS}) OR {Header.StreetS} = "" THEN "" ELSE {Header.StreetS} & CHR(13)
& IF ISNULL({Header.ZipCodeS}) OR {Header.ZipCodeS} = "" THEN "" ELSE {Header.ZipCodeS} & ' '
& IF ISNULL({Header.CityS}) OR {Header.CityS} = "" THEN "" ELSE {Header.CityS} & CHR(13)
& IF ISNULL({Header.BlockS}) OR {Header.BlockS} = "" THEN "" ELSE {Header.BlockS} & CHR(13)
& IF ISNULL({Header.CountryS}) OR {Header.CountryS} = "" THEN "" ELSE {Header.CountryS}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying thing I've seen many times.

The problem is that you can't evaluate `ISNULL({Column})` and `{Column} = ""` in the same `IF`-clause.

Because `{Column} = ""` will be evaluated even if `ISNULL` already returned `True`.

This should work:

```
  IF ISNULL({Header.StreetS}) THEN "" ELSE IF {Header.StreetS} = "" THEN "" ELSE {Header.StreetS} & CHR(13)
& IF ISNULL({Header.ZipCodeS}) THEN "" ELSE IF {Header.ZipCodeS} = "" THEN "" ELSE {Header.ZipCodeS} & ' '
& IF ISNULL({Header.CityS}) THEN "" ELSE IF {Header.CityS} = "" THEN "" ELSE {Header.CityS} & CHR(13)
& IF ISNULL({Header.BlockS}) THEN "" ELSE IF {Header.BlockS} = "" THEN "" ELSE {Header.BlockS} & CHR(13)
& IF ISNULL({Header.CountryS}) THEN "" ELSE IF {Header.CountryS} = "" THEN "" ELSE {Header.CountryS}
```